# Silverlight 4 open pdf file in native client application

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Hi i am working on a silverlight4 application running in browser. now i am trying to open PDF files but pdf files being opened in new tab of the browser. I want them to be open in native  application as adobe or acrobat reader if installed. otherwise prompt a message to user. Any help is welcome. i tried many ways but nothing seems to be working.Tried to use AutomationFactory but not available.

Answer (score 0):

Uri uri = new Uri(searchFolder, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri, "_blank", "Left=0,Top=0,Width=900,Height=500,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");